# Ionic5 hardware Backbutton event not triggered in new android device with swipe to back or backbutton available in navigation bar

Tags: ionic-framework, back-button, ionic5

In ionic5 i tried to generate backbutton event in new android phone which use either swipe to back functionality or which had navigationbar with back button.
In that devices I just open app and then swipe back at same time this event not working.But if i perform some action on that page like press menu button and swipe back at that time this event called and run perfectly.

I also tried to change priority of event but still not working.

In old android phone which had hardware back button in that same backbuttonevent working.But in new android phone same event not working when I just open app and swipe back.

```
this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
  if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/tabs/customer-dashboard') || this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/vendor-dashboard')) {
    this.commonService.askConfirmation();
  } else if (this.close && this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo('/tabs/active-booking-list')) {
    this.commonService.askConfirmation();
  } else {
    this.location.back();
  }
});
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If I understand correctly you want the back button to exit the app when at top of the navigation stack?

Comment: @E.Maggini As far as I understand he wants to capture `Back Button` event which is not available in new phones as there are no Hardware back button. so how can he capture that event on swipe back gesture?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Yes but OP states that after performing an action back swipe works as expected which makes sense since history stack would have somewhere to go "back" to. But when you are on the first page there is nowhere to go "back" so I presume the desire is to close the app.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib  I want show confirmation message before exiting the app.Now in new android devices when I just open app and swipe to back action performed my back button event not generating.But when i perfrm some action on page not changing the page and then I swipe back then swipe back event worked correctly.

Comment: I assume your `Platform` is not ready and when your platform gets ready your event will be available! try it inside `platform.ready()` and see if it works.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib but when there is hardware back button in android phone it works currectly.My whole page is also rendred.So ultimately Platform is ready.Issue arries for new android phones only